# streaming video from a ros topic to a client browser

Tags: ros, video, webcam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to stream live data from my robot to the internet.

Right now I have a ROS node communicating with a webcam and publishing Image/CompressedImage data. The robot needs this data to follow lines/recognize obstacles. I'm trying to figure out how to have the data be sent to show up in a browser in realtime video. I'm not sure on the best way to go about this.

I could have the computer running ROS also be running a server, copying jpeg/png CompressedImage data to a file, then have a client connect to that server to periodically poll for the image and update its page to simulate video..

Is there a more common/better approach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46349/streaming-video-from-a-ros-topic-to-a-client-browser/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are possibly interested in the [mjpeg_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/mjpeg_server).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a package named [`ros_bridge`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge) that has been designed to be used in project like yours.  In the [PR2 Remote Lab project](http://pr2-remotelab.com/doku.php?id=start), they implemented such web-based video broadcasting. I think in this [paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6224653), there are some more technical information about video streaming using `ros_bridge`.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2